Handling Varbinary Datatype in Node.JS API header with SQL Server
The API program didn't accept a varbinary format for my Node.JS API with a header key and varbinary value to authenticate my API request with Node.JS.
I've tried the straightforward approach by initializing this code in my authenticate Node.JS function,
const encryptHeader = req.headers[process.env.API_HEADER];

const apiKey = await request.input('encryptHeader', sql.VarBinary, encryptHeader)
    .query('EXEC spAPI @encryptHeader');

...with other structures of my code that are unnecessary to include here
I expect that it should work as expected which it will accept the varbinary key input along with my header for my API authentication (e.g., 0x01000000AAA), then the SQL Server would return a value from its Stored Procedure.

For variable length data types you usually need to specify a length of some kind. Have you tried specifying a length? e.g.: if the @encryptHeader parameter is varbinary(50) then try sql.VarBinary(50); if it's varbinary(max) then try sql.VarBinary(sql.MAX). See the mssql documentation for other examples.
